# Best way to convert HTML to plaintext using Python

Tags: python, html, plaintext

I'm working on a project that involves converting a large amount of HTML content to plain/text. I have a custom-written module that does the job OK, but I'm wondering if there's some standard tools to help get the job done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Html2Text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) seems to be a good option

Comment: The site is no longer accessible since Aaron, the author is no longer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a python library which does HTML parsing:

- [lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html)

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is another option.

Comment: To save others some time circling from Google back to SO, here is a Q&A describing that Beautiful Soup is not really maintained anymore: [WebScraping with BeautifulSoup or LXML.HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493514/webscraping-with-beautifulsoup-or-lxml-html).

Comment: Beautiful Soup appears to be maintained now I think.