# Beautiful soup - Unable to create csv and text files after scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the URL's of articles from all the pages of a website. Only the URLs in the first page are repeatedly scraped and stored in the csv file.
The information from these links are again scraped the same way and stored in the text file.

Need some help in this issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml
import urllib2

base_url = 'https://www.marketingweek.com/?s=big+data'
response = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

res = []

while 1:
    search_results = soup.find('div', class_='archive-constraint') #localizing search window with article links
    article_link_tags = search_results.findAll('a') #ordinary scheme goes further 
    res.append([url['href'] for url in article_link_tags])
    #Automatically clicks next button to load other articles
    next_button = soup.find('a', text='>>')
    #Searches for articles till Next button is not found
    if not next_button:
        break
    res.append([url['href'] for url in article_link_tags])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for i in res:
        for j in i:
                print(j)
####Storing scraped links in csv file###

with open('StoreUrl1.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.seek(0)
    for i in res:
        for j in i:
            f.write('\n'.join(i))


#######Extracting info from URLs########

with open('StoreUrl1.csv', 'rb') as f1:
    f1.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(f1)

    for line in reader:
        url = line[0]       
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), "lxml")

        with open('InfoOutput1.txt', 'a+') as f2:
            for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
                f2.write(tag.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using html parser of lxml.**

There are 361 pages and on each page we have 12 links. We can iterate to each page and extract the links using xpath.

xpath helps in getting:

- Text under a particular tag
- Value of particular tag (here: value of 'href' attribute of 'a' tag)

  ```
  import csv
  from lxml import html
  from time import sleep
  import requests
  from random import randint

  outputFile = open("All_links.csv", r'wb')
  fileWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)

  fileWriter.writerow(["Sl. No.", "Page Number", "Link"])

  url1 = 'https://www.marketingweek.com/page/'
  url2 = '/?s=big+data'

  sl_no = 1

  #iterating from 1st page through 361th page
  for i in xrange(1, 362):

      #generating final url to be scraped using page number
      url = url1 + str(i) + url2

      #Fetching page
      response = requests.get(url)
      sleep(randint(10, 20))
      #using html parser
      htmlContent = html.fromstring(response.content)

      #Capturing all 'a' tags under h2 tag with class 'hentry-title entry-title'
      page_links = htmlContent.xpath('//div[@class = "archive-constraint"]//h2[@class = "hentry-title entry-title"]/a/@href')
      for page_link in page_links:
          fileWriter.writerow([sl_no, i, page_link])
          sl_no += 1
  ```

Comment: got this error in the end  `File "C:\Users\Rajesh Ramesh\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Final website scraping - 2\Final website scraping - 2\Final_website_scraping___2.py", line 381, in <module>
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 421, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 283, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: Link`

Comment: Could u please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to print `next_button`, it is `None`. Why we need the `a` tag of next button if we can directly go to specific page by slightly modifying the url. In your code, suppose either way you have found the link to next page but didn't get the `text` of the element returned by `soup.find('a',text=">>")`. Here is your modified code. Let me know if it works for you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

import urllib2
df = pd.DataFrame()
base_url = 'https://www.marketingweek.com/?s=big+data'

res = []
page = 1
while page < 362:
    page_url = 'https://www.marketingweek.com/page/'+str(page)+'/?s=big+data'
    response = requests.get(page_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    search_results = soup.find('div', class_='columns-flex full-ads') #localizing search window with article links
    try:
        article_link_tags = search_results.findAll('a') #ordinary scheme goes further 
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    res.append([url['href'] for url in article_link_tags])


    print('Found {} links on page {} '.format(len(res[page-1]), page))

    df.append(res[page-1])
    #for i in res:
    #    for j in i:
    #            print(j)
    page += 1
    # break
####Storing scraped links in csv file###
df.to_csv('SampleUrl.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: any explanations?

Comment: @ksai No. The article URLs in the first page are only displayed and scraped.

Comment: Obviously it would scrape the first page, but how it would scrape the 2nd page without clicking either next button or browsing the page by url.

Comment: Finding the `a` tag for next button was slightly difficult as compared to changing the url.

Comment: @ksai - the modification u had suggested did not work. Any alternate solution?

Comment: @ksai No errors or warnings. Just the same output (as stated initially in the question). Only the first page's article URLs get printed. That's it.

Comment: @RRR Did you try to remove the last `break` statement in my code. I commented that line.

Comment: @ksai I removed the last break. All the links get displayed but finally this error appears - **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'** pointing to `article_link_tags = search_results.findAll('a')`  Also the csv & text files don't get created.

Comment: @RRR I wrapped that in `try-except`. Now try running the code.

Comment: @ksai No errors now. Takes about one hour to retrieve everything. But still doesn't create the csv and txt files.

Comment: @RRR I didn't checked the _csv writing_ part because the question was about crawling beyond first page.

Comment: @ksai I'm sorry for the lack of clarity. Could u please guide me in that as well?

Comment: @RRR So it's better you update the question as well. The url is like `https://www.marketingweek.com/2015/08/25/how-marketers-can-win-the-big-data-revolution/`, Do you want to write this url exactly

Comment: @ksai yes. I will be accessing the csv file to extract respective information into a txt file for sentiment analysis.

Comment: @RRR I need to do **####Storing scraped links in csv file###** part only

Comment: @RRR See the updated code, you may need to install [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Comment: @ksai I had used pandas before, but it was not useful. Tried your updated code, the csv file is empty

Answer (score 0):

I only healed url collection part:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

next_button = 'https://www.marketingweek.com/page/1/?s=big+data'

res = []

while 1:
    response = requests.get(next_button)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    search_results = soup.find('div', class_='archive-constraint') #localizing search window with article links
    article_link_tags = search_results.findAll('a') #ordinary scheme goes further 

    #added duplication drop from list of urls
    row = [url['href'] for url in article_link_tags] 
    row = list(set(row))

    res.append(row)

    #Automatically clicks next button to load other articles
    next_button = soup.find('a', class_='next page-numbers')
    #Searches for articles till Next button is not found
    if not next_button:
        break
    next_button = next_button['href']

for i in res:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

**EDIT**: First version of code faced parser bot blocking on site. These fixes below *might* help (for 100% assurance you need to know how bots blocker works on the site). I added both random `sleep` from 5 to 30 sec and random `user-agent` change (only desktop user-agents) in requests to site to skip blocking:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agents = {0:
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246',
1:
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36',
2:
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9',
3:
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36',
4:
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'}

next_button = 'https://www.marketingweek.com/page/1/?s=big+data'
res = []

while 1:
    response = requests.get(next_button, headers={'User-Agent':user_agents[np.random.randint(0,5)]})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    search_results = soup.find('div', class_='columns-flex full-ads') #localizing search window with article links
    article_link_tags = search_results.findAll('a') #ordinary scheme goes further 

    #added duplication drop from list of urls
    row = [url['href'] for url in article_link_tags] 
    row = list(set(row))

    res.append(row)

    #Automatically clicks next button to load other articles
    next_button = soup.find('a', class_='next page-numbers')
    #Searches for articles till Next button is not found
    if not next_button:
        break
    next_button = next_button['href']

    time.sleep((30 - 5) * np.random.random() + 5)

for i in res:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

If it still fails after some time, try to extend `sleep` twice or bigger.

Comment: Unfortunately the output screen is blank.Nothing is printed.

Comment: the processing of required site will take a lot of time, maybe you didn't wait till script finishes?
I manually stopped script execution after approx. 30 sec. and got `res` containing 6 lists of urls.

Comment: Ok I shall do as advised.

Comment: Got this error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'** for the line `article_link_tags = search_results.findAll('a')`

Comment: did you _copy and paste_ my code as is? This error means that `search_results` for particular page is empty. Easily can be healed with `try-except`. But you won't collect links for that particular page obviously. Or should be done some bigger workaround.

Comment: ok, this error is thrown on 10th page. If you look at `soup` value after error it will be obvious that site server blocked your scraper. You need to change user-agents and/or implement random sleep.

Comment: added both fixes in solution

Comment: Tried thrice..took a long time but unsuccessful. Going to test again. Shall update soon.

Comment: unsuccessful because of what? errors again? or something else?

Comment: Just got a blank screen. I was waiting for something to come up since you told it would take some time. I kept waiting for a long time, but nothing appeared.

Comment: Why I get results and you do not? did you check `res`? does it contain lists of urls?

Comment: No. I get a user unhandled error at `from _elementtree import`